# How to remove Dots from the Start and End points of a line in MAPSUI

Tags: mapsui

There's a line in mentioned picture which has a dot at both endpoints.
Referring to the issue https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/issues/956 , it only works for point feature. However if we draw shapes like line, polygons, these dots appear on end points of vertices/lines and are not removed by using Layer.style= null. Source code is used from the following branch
https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/tree/master/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Wpf.Editing/Editing
The code for this line is  "if else" in the method Addvertex present in Editmanager.cs[Click for  view the problem in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIyJU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the editing sample those dots were added on purpose because they can be dragged and added and deleted. I don't know by heart which style layer this is and do not have to code at hand. You should be able to find it if you search for Style or Styles in the Mapsui.Samples.Wpf.Editing project.